# IPA size and performance

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi I am trying to understand how ipa size matters in iOS app development. My app is having almost 60MB IPA size and I am trying to know does it matter?

If yes does it affect app performance/ memory? My understanding is - performance is only depends upon how we allocate and release objects in memory.

Comment: Should only effect initial download size from app store.

Comment: If you try to reduce the size of assets then the size of ipa will be reduce, the rest are depend on number and types of framework sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
My app is having almost 60MB IPA size and I am trying to know does it matter?
```

The IPA size impacts the download size of the app from the app store. The actual download size is not the same because the IPAs are downloaded in compressed form and then retrieved after download.

```
My understanding is - performance only depends upon how we allocate and release objects in memory.
```

You are correct about the performance aspect. The performance depends on the way you allocate/deallocate the memory and how fast your operations are.

Though, if you have too many dynamic frameworks, it will increase your app launch time because those frameworks are loaded into the memory on each app launch.

P.S.
To reduce your IPA size, make sure your assets are compressed.